# How is secure passing a Bearer Token from two web application using query string?

Tags: javascript, api, security

I have two web applications (prototype) hosted on two sub-domains, example:

1) A CMS (done in PHP) at cms.mydomain.com.

2) A SPA - Singe page web application (done in **JavaScript**) at spa.mydomain.com.

My User case:

User can access CMS app and authenticate using Username and Password.

After authentication is successfully completed a web page with some items is presented on CMS app.

User can select an item and than *open on a new window with SPA application*.

At the moment, after authentication is completed in CMS app a **Bearer Token** is created, we are passing the TOKEN to the SPA app as **query string** in order to authenticate the User.

SPA app JavaScript retrieves the query string and other additional parameters and execute API call in order to function.

Notes:

- We are using HTTPS on both applications.
- SPA application can be accessed only after authentication in CMS.
- SPA application which receive the token is on an .HTML file and API calls are made using JS only.
- Bearer Token has validity of 14 days.
- The token give full access to SPA application.
- The token could be passed from CMD to SPA using also JS.
- Tokens are generated by a third application api.mysite.com.

I am aware that TOKEN in query strings could be unsecured because:

- URLs with their query strings parameters are saved in web server log, and access to them could compromise security.
- Third party application like Google Analytic could store in their report such URLs and query string.

I would like to know your opinion on:

- What could be a safe way to pass the token from CMS to APP without using query string?
- I am thinking if [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) could be used in CMS to send the token as message to SPA. Do you see any security issue with this approach?
- What other risk I could encounter if using query strings (I need to convince my team query string is not a good approach - if true :) )?
- Could you point me out some additional resource or guidelines?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: use hash instead of search: it's not left behind in logs or even sent over the network with the request. you don't need postMessage is the popup is on the same domain. you can also use `localStorage` or `window.name` if hash is not an option.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for your comment, Google Analytic or similar softwares can track hastag on url and localStorage won't work on my specific case as the two apps are on two subdomains. As far I know localStorage has some limitation for security reasons. Any other ideas is welcome, thanks for sharing.

Comment: i still think hash is better than search, but postMessage is the best way.

Comment: I'm facing a pretty similar situation in which I have a fully standalone SPA app, hosted on a its own domain, which is embedded in a web application, as a module, through an iframe, and I'm currently handling authorization by passing an auth token, created specifically for that app, as a query parameter which the SPA takes and sends to its own backend which decrypts it. Everything is served over HTTPS and the token is unique each time, but I'm still not convinced about sharing that data, even if encrypted, by using URL query params. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps create a one-time access token to the SPA rather than sending the original bearer token as the query string.

This token could then be sent to the API, decoded and used to create the real auth token, but would have the advantage of only being valid once. Now you no longer need to worry about server logs, GA, etc. I suppose it's a form of redirection to alleviate those concerns.